# Etiquetas y leyenda a dos variables ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

He estado intentando poner etiquetas a varias variables en un mismo gráfico en ggplot. El siguiente ejemplo aclara la pregunta:

```
df<-data.frame("a"=rnorm(100,150,30), "b"=rnorm(100,150,30),"c"=rnorm(100,150,30))

ggplot(data=df,aes())+geom_density(aes(x=a))+geom_density(aes(x=b))+geom_density(aes(x=c))
```

Cómo asigno la etiqueta a las variables "a", "b", "c"?
(por favor solucionar en el ejemplo)

Gracias

---

La verdad tengo un data frame con 108 variables y 242mil observaciones, las variables que voy a graficar no están en orden, no puedo utilizar melt, mi código en realidad es el siguiente:

```
ggplot(data=DF, aes(x=DF$VAR60)) +
  geom_density(aes(x=DF$VAR70), size=1) + 
  geom_density(aes(x=DF$VAR85),  size=1)+
  geom_density(aes(x=DF$VAR102),  size=1)+
  geom_density(aes(x=DF$VAR95),  size=0.7)+
  geom_density(aes(x=DF$VAR52), size=1)+
  ggtitle("Distribución Pruebas Saber Pro")+geom_vline(xintercept = 150, size = 1.2, colour="grey")
```

NO he podido asignar la etiqueta, ni la leyenda al gráfico. Gracias por su colaboración

Answer (score 1):

Esta es la forma más simple de configurar lo que preguntas, básicamente tienes que establecer que cada línea tiene su propio color, de manera que puedas identificarlas en el gráfico. De paso te muestro de que forma definir el resto de las etiquetas y títulos del gráfico

```
library(ggplot2)
df<-data.frame("a"=rnorm(100,150,30), "b"=rnorm(100,150,30),"c"=rnorm(100,150,30))
ggplot(df)+
    geom_density(aes(x=a, colour="a")) +
    geom_density(aes(x=b, colour="b")) +
    geom_density(aes(x=c, colour="c")) +
    scale_color_discrete(name='Etiquetas') +
    scale_x_continuous(name = "Etiqueta eje X") +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Etiqueta eje Y") +
    ggtitle("Titulo")
```

Quedaría algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias. Cómo puedo ahora cambiar los nombres de las etiquetas, no quiero que se llamen "a", "b" o "c".

Comment: Para modificar el nombre de la etiqueta simplemente modificas `geom_density(aes(x=a, colour="El nombre que quiera"))`

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! Yo trataría el problema de la siguiente manera:

```
# Utilizar la función melt
  # Cargar librería
    library(reshape2)
    # Utilizar la función
      TAB <- melt(df)
# Representación gráfica
  ggplot(TAB)+
  stat_density(aes(x=value, colour=variable),geom="line",position="identity")
```

Automáticamente te genera la leyenda y te diferencia por color cada una de las curvas de densidad.